# Similar term to "visual" for audio?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a term for *audio* in form of the word *visual*.

*Visual* is defined as

> of or relating to the sense of sight

**What could you call the sense of hearing?**
Also, what do you call this form of a word? (i.e *verb, noun*...)

It should fit the x in the following sentence:

> *Is it possible to fall in love with someone without visual or x contact?*

I'm not a native English speaker, so I couldn't find the terms for searching this.

Comment: What's wrong with plain old "***audible***"?

Comment: It doesn't fit the sentence. It's not a similar sounding word to visual which is what I was looking for.

Comment: "Visual" doesn't really fit the sentence very well either. The term "visual contact" is rather rare, and could be easily confused with "eye contact" - which isn't quite what you mean.

Comment: @DanBron “*visible* is to *audible* as *visual* is to ____?” is what the OP is asking I believe.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Aural* - of or relating to the ear or the sense of hearing.  It's an *adjective.*

Comment: _Audial_ and _auricular_ are synonyms also. _Aural_ seems like the most common one (if we exclude _auditory_). [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=audial%2Caural%2Cauricular%2Cauditory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caudial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caural%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauricular%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauditory%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: If audial is the very same thing, it's more what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Claudio: Even, _audio_ is an adjective itself.

Comment: Discovered this while reading page 5 of "Code" by Charles Petzold today: "...types of information used in communication, be it visual (text and pictures), aural (spoken words, sounds, and music)..."

Comment: Honestly, I'd prefer to go with "auditory" for the sole reason that "aural" and "oral" are nearly indistinguishable when spoken. Consider in context, "Is it possible to fall in love with someone without oral contact?"

Comment: I think "aural" is more about the ear organ itself, whereas "auditory" is about the sense of hearing. They are very close, and are often interchangeable, but there is a slight distinction. It's the same distinction between "ocular" and "visual".

Comment: how is _audio_ an adjective? it is the 1st person form of _audire_ (just as _video_ is that of _videre_)

Answer (score 26):

auditory - adjective - of or relating to the sense of hearing.
"the auditory nerves"

Comment: I guess it means the same thing, but it's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

**Ocular**: relating to the eye(s) | **Aural**: relating to the ear(s)

**Visible**: able to be seen | **Audible**: able to be heard

**Visual**: relating to the sense of sight/seeing | **Auditory**: relating to the sense of hearing

**Video**: relating to light or the recording thereof | **Audio**: relating to sound or the recording thereof

**Photo-**: produced by light | **Phono-**/**Sono-**: produced by sound or voice

**Verbal**: relating to words (either written or spoken)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be:

> Is it possible to fall in love with someone without visual or **verbal** contact?

"Verbal" refers to speech, rather than hearing, but seems to convey the message well in this case.

Alternatively, you may want to use the term face-to-face, for example "without meeting face-to-face".

Comment: But this can mean a chat message. The sentence belongs to an article where it is wondered, can you fall in love through internet rather than face to face.

Comment: @Claudio Then I misunderstood the question. I thought the rules were no video or audio contact whatsoever, not even online, but only text contact. I would recommend writing "without face-to-face contact" or "without meeting face-to-face" to best convey the message.

Comment: Good idea. It's easier for people to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Aural and auditory are both technically correct in this sentence, but neither works well. While aural sounds better in cadence with "visual," it is the lesser choice because in addition to meaning "relating to the sense of hearing" it can mean "relating to the ear." "Aural contact" could thus be interpreted as touching the ear!

The problem is the sentence itself: "visual and auditory contact" is extremely awkward. So write around it: "Is it possible to fall in love without actually meeting the person?"

Comment: 'Aural' also sounds exactly the same as 'oral' in many varieties of spoken English, making it very prone to generating confusion. However, in context, 'auditory' would be perfectly acceptable: in normal speech, I have never heard it used to mean 'pertaining to the external ear'. For most people in most situations, it means only 'relating to the sense of hearing'.

Comment: It should be auditory- Listen to the *aural* sensations of songs from outer space when you've been gassed for your *oral* surgery. Then stay non-*verbal* because you can't use words for a long time after the dentist wakes you up.

Comment: Your phrasing doesn't work since "meeting in person" doesn't preclude talking on the phone, which is auditory.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the OP nobody has provided this answer yet:

In high school the students that operated the picture projectors and sound systems belonged to the "audio-visual" club. I believe that is the best answer to the question. Don't change it at all.

**"Is it possible to fall in love with someone without visual or audio contact?"**

[Audio *adjective*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/audio_1) connected with sound and the recording and broadcasting of sound: an audiocasette, audiotape, an audio signal

Audio and visual go together like peanut butter and jelly. The other answers suggested here seem far less usual to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to fall in love with someone without the warmth of their gaze or the comfort of their voice?

Is it possible to fall in love with someone without the sights and sounds of your lover?

Is it possible to fall in love with someone without retinal or tympanic excitation?

Just throwin' things out here.

Answer (score 0):

**acoustic** 
*(adjective)*:
relating to sound or the sense of hearing.

would this work?

-- A

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange seeks *definitive* answers; you should explain why you propose a word, supported with appropriate references and examples, and by the same token if you are not sure about it, you should not suggest it. *Acoustic* is not commonly used in the sense requested in the original question. In any event, I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

visual  - sonic
visually - sonically

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. An answer really needs to have its sources revealed, otherwise it is simply opinion. You may have a good answer, but it needs to have citations from reputable sources to be taken seriously.

Comment: How does "aural" not fit your bill, please?